# How can I tell if my Python Installation is "bundled"?

Tags: python, installation, bundle, cx-oracle

I'm installing a package (cx_Oracle), and the [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-macos-intel-x86) says:

> Make sure you are not using the bundled Python. This has restricted
> entitlements and will fail to load Oracle client libraries.

I'm wondering: how do I tell if my Python installation (if I did not install it) is "bundled" or not?

Answer (score 0):

Normally in MAC OS python comes along with installation of OS itself that means python package included in OS files also called as bundled python. You can check if the python you are using is bundled or not by

```
which python
```

On mac os
you should get output like if it's a bundled python

```
/usr/bin/python
```

when you want to get the path of externally installed python by

```
which python3
```

The only difference is
When you type

```
python
```

in terminal it launches pre-installed or bundled python.
If you type

```
python3
```

in terminal it  launches externally installed python in this cases what the oracle documentation is recommended